# Creating new script from output

Tags: powershell

Hoping this will be an easy one for somebody, but I just don't have the experience.  I'm pulling the mapped network drive info from a PC.  I'm testing the path to make sure it's active and that the person still has access.  The test works fine.  Here's my issue...

If the test is $true, I want it to output a line of code to a new .ps1 file for remapping the drive.  I think I'm just about there, but I can't wrap my head around outputting a line of code and not the output of the line.  Thanks for any help!

```
foreach ($Drive IN $Drives)
{
    $MND = $Network.OpenSubKey("$Drive")
    $Share = $MND.GetValue("RemotePath")
    $Path = Test-Path "$Share\*"
    IF ($Path -eq $true)
    {
        $ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"
        Stop-Transcript | out-null
        $ErrorActionPreference = "Continue"
        Start-Transcript -path C:\output.ps1 -append
        "New-PSDrive -Name "$Drive" -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "$Share" -Persist"
        Stop-Transcript
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm an idiot.  Instead of making it so hard on myself, I changed the whole IF to a single line "New-PSDrive -Name $Drive -PSProvider FileSystem -Root $Share -Persist" | Out-File C:\output.ps1 -Append

Answer (score 1):

Per your comment, you probably don't want to be using `Start-Transcript` (as you'd get a lot of header content that you don't want), but rather something that outputs to a file like `Out-File -Append` or `Add-Content`.

You also need to remove the internal double quotes which are likely unnecessary (or you could replace them with single quotes):

```
"New-PSDrive -Name $Drive -PSProvider FileSystem -Root $Share -Persist" | Add-Content c:\output.ps1
```

It's worth also checking you have rights to write files to the root of C:\, this is blocked by default for non-admins in later versions of Windows.

Comment: Appreciate the tips!  The root file was just an example.  I'm writing to a folder on my desktop.  I also discovered that I wanted to change it up a little more, because I'm doing this remotely and don't want to know if I have permissions.  So I'm having it create the script with the whole Test-Path and such, as well.  Just wanted to give a "Where Is He Now" update haha.  Thanks again!